# data relationship modeling and Django

Tags: python, database, django, relational-database

This question might be really easy but for the life of me i cant get my head around this today...

I have been asked by work to learn Django so i have donned my cap and been working on tutorials and the such the last couple of days. however i have a problem i could do with some help with.

I have this basic data model:

table1

Datasets - Id, Name

table2

subcatergory - id, dataset_id,name

table3

subcatergory value - id,subcat_id,value

so 1 dataset can have many subcatergories and 1 subcatergory can have many values.

in django i have this:

```
class Dataset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class SubCat(models.Model):
    dataset = models.ForeignKey(Dataset)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class SubCatVal(models.Model):
    subcat = models.ForeignKey(SubCat)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

in the views.py when i am testing it (i am basically atm just wanting to fill some drop boxes) if i do `d = Dataset.objects.all()` then the object `d` have no knowlegde of the sub catergories?

so i if i wanted it all i would have to do:

```
d  = Dataset.objects.all();
s  = SubCat.objects.all();
sv = SubCatVal.objects.all();
```

then in the html do something like

```
{% for d in  dataset %}
    {% for s in subcat %}
        {% if s.dataset_id == d.id %}
            //add {{s.name}} to a select box
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

is this the way to do this? or am i totally missing a trick?

thanks

Comment: it's "category", not "catergory"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the docs on getting related objects:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

In short: yes, it'll be something like:

```
# in view, passed to template
datasets = Dateset.objects.all()
# template
{% for d in datasets %}
    {% for s in d.subcat_set.all %}
        <option value="{{ s.id }}">{{ s.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reference the foreign keys from Dataset with `dObject.subcat_set.all()`, which will list all of the subcategories for the dObject object. Similarly, you can get all the SubCatValues with `subcatObject.subcatval_set.all()`. This is a bit besides the point, though, as you should be creating forms programatically with a `Form` or `ModelForm` object, and not writing them yourself manually in the HTML.

Comment: The [Accessing foreign key values](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10/#cn7) section in the django book should be useful to get further information on this.

Comment: @jknupp - I understand about using the form object, however its kind of a funky despoke problem ^^

Answer (score -1):

read [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/) for how to store & retrieve related objects.

Comment: "so 1 dataset can have many subcategories and 1 subcategory can have many values."  This makes it backwards.

Comment: yes! this is the way it is done on django ORM, and it gives you a set magic querying options.

Comment: No, it's not. Your code would only allow one subcat per dataset and subcatval per subcat.

Comment: @AdamKG you are right! sorry I misunderstood the requirements.